# Combine two or more tables into a third separate table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have an excel workbook that has three pivot tables in it. What I am wanting to do is create a fourth table that combines the data from all three of the other tables.

Essentially I want to concatenate the tables together but still preserve the source tables.

Another criteria of what I am wanting to do is if I add a row to any of the source tables it must update the combined table and it must work with x amount of rows where x could be any size.

I know I am asking a lot but I would be so grateful if I could get some help working this out. I am comfortable with using either VBA or native excel to solve this.

If you guys need examples I will be happy to upload some.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could move the data into database tables, perhaps using Microsoft Access, perhaps using something better. You could then use those database tables as data-sources for the Excel worksheets.

- [Microsoft Article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010167227.aspx)
- [MSQuery](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/msquery1_1.htm)

Comment: I found a solution using VBA